# javascript memory/match 2 game

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple memory game in javascript. I have an issue, and that is, the images don't hide if they don't match.

```
 function guess() {
   var pnode;
   var click = 0;
   numberOfClicks++;
   if(click == 0) {
     this.childNodes[0].style.visibility = "visible";
     pnode =this.childNodes[0];
     click++;
   } else if(click == 1) {
     tnode = this.childNodes[0];
     tnode.style.visibility = "visible";
     if(pnode.src != tnode.src) {
       setTimeout(function () {
         pnode.style.visibility = "hidden";
         tnode.style.visibility = "hidden";
       }, 2000);
     }
     click = 0;
   }
 }
```

I have my images in a table and their visibility set to hidden and this function executes when a table cell is clicked.

Comment: first, `if(klik == 0)` => `if(click == 0)` I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the `click` and `pnode` variables that you've made local to the function.

So, considering the two first lines of your function, each time you call `guess()`, `click` will be set to 0 and `pnode` to undefined.

Use global variables if you want to keep their value across different calls.